# When there is a Javascript error, Socket.IO disconnect and prevent debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, socket.io-1.0

so i don't know if it's a new thing in socket.io 1.1.0 but whenever i have a javascript error, anywhere in my code (even when it doesn't involve socket.io at all), socket.io is simply disconnecting (it calls the disconnect event and also the error event with an TransportError error) and then... nothing shows up in the firefox console nor chrome console, no debug info, nothing, and it doesn't help me to find the error...

is there a way to prevent socket.io to do that or is it a thing to do with websockets or something ?

Comment: my suggestion is try { ... } catch { ... }, with async so that you can maintain the stacktrace

Comment: why not make a small project to test...where it connects to the server and see if it can echo...then randomly (or have a button) throw an error outside of socket io and inside of socket io to see if there is a disconnect...my guess is there is an issue with the server as i have never had this issue with the client

Comment: Can you post your code & let me know whats your node.js debug log shows

Comment: i got it right, so all i needed apparently was to activate the socket.io debug like i found it here http://socket.io/docs/logging-and-debugging/. thanks to all of you anyway, your advices helped me discover that